# Alternative for old ika in Blender

Tags: animation, rigging

Blender had once upon a time such IKA systems i miss. I Used the IKA to animate pneumatic pump.

I realy try to switch to armatures but stuck on it since years, they are very complex. [image: pneumatic]

The way i did it in the version 1.80a was to:

1. add two sticks (big, small).
2. add an ika in both sticks
3. parenting the sticks to the ikas.
4. parenting the ika to each other ika.

The Armatures-Objects looks like a much more complex feature than i need.

Any idea how to construct this is a new blender version?

Comment: does ika have anything to do with inverse kinematics (a-something)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using an armature you can use parenting and constraints.

- Starting with two cylinders, add two empties. The empties should be located at opposing ends of each cylinder.
- Select a cylinder then Shift select the matching empty and parent them with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> -> Object. Repeat for other cylinder and empty.
- Select a cylinder and add a TrackTo constraint. Set the target to be the empty of the opposing piston and set the axis to suit. Repeat for other cylinder.

[image]

Now as you move one of the empties the two pistons will always point towards each other. If you position one of the empties at the outer edge of a disc and parent the empty to the disc it will rotate around with it and the cylinders will follow.

[image]

Here is a sample file to look at. [image]