# Parenting problem on front axle: need too many parents

Tags: game-engine

[image: Crane Front Axle]

The important parts here are the large middle piece, the axle, the two pivots that allow the wheels to steer, between the axle and the tires, and the tie rod between the two pivots. The pivots are children of the axle. Here's the hard part: the tie rod needs to be the parent of both the pivots to keep the tie rod in place, and to cause both pivots to move together.
One parent can have many children, but one object can only have one parent. 
So, how does the tie rod keep both pivots together?
This is all in Logic Bricks, without python or animation, please.

Comment: Constraints should work in the GE, so [this may help](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/77103/935).  You parent one end and point it at the position of the other end.

Comment: @sambler good answer, gave you an up vote on that page.