# Making a bone rig for piston

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

I'm trying to make a bone rig for a piston which will be a part of active aerodynamics of a vehicle.

I did find a video but it was on older version of Blender and confused me halfway.

How to make an armature which does the following:

(a) has a sliding movement for piston

(b) has a angular movement on which causes the piston to operate, or vice versa.

Considering that, one part of piston is a fixed to a body and the other part is what does the sliding movement. This sliding movement is connected to an upright bone which rotates on the other free end's axis.

To put it simply the upright bone is being rotated to a certain angle by the piston. The upright bone is 90°, the default angle, pointing upwards."

Comment: And what **exactly** is your question? Please read [this](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please).

Comment: Maybe drivers are what you need (especially see the middle part of the video) https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=8_n-dooMQmU

Comment: Another option with an armature: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=vWjxdn1R0Ek

Comment: What exactly do you mean by: "be a part of active aerodynamics of a vehicle"?

Comment: Please show how your piston is supposed to work, you don't say enough

Comment: I want to use a hydraulic piston for "active aerodynamics". In Automobile Industry, Active Aerodynamics or Active Aero means a ability of a Hypercar or Sportscar to obtain variable amount of downforce. So by "a part of active aero" means there are multiple components which are collectively called active aero on the vehicle I'm making.  To put it simply, I want a bone rig for piston's movement. For example, the one part of a hydraulic piston is supposed to slide into another part of the piston, the sliding movement. I'm making bone rig just for that.

Comment: And for reference, the part I'm working is called Active spoiler/wing. Check Koenigsegg Agera One:1 's Wing in action and you'll get what I'm trying to do.

Comment: https://youtu.be/JxslsUXyCro A link for the above mentioned car's wing in action. And this is another one, but in a more informative way https://youtu.be/jOoS6FBoQZM

Comment: It would help if you edited your question and added a question sentence, e.g. "I want effect A, I tried B, it doesn't work because of C, how can I achieve A?" with a question mark.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102990/how-can-one-rig-a-stirling-engine/103000#103000 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86804/rigging-an-umbrella-like-object/86921#86921

Comment: I edited the question, the links provided were towards more complex systems. What I want is actually a simple system. I have provided the links which show exactly what I want.

Comment: People here know blender or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with 3D models, we often work the opposite way to reality, that is we would animate the aerofoil rotating and have the attached parts move to follow its movement. For what you are after you may not need any more than rotating the aerofoil, the interconnecting pieces of a cars rear spoiler may not even be visible.

There are a collection of [constraints](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/rigging/constraints/index.html) available that can simplify automated interactions of multiple components.

A piston is composed of two parts, one fitting inside the other and both pieces pointing toward the fixture point of the other. The [TrackTo constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/rigging/constraints/tracking/track_to.html) is the easiest way to keep the two piston pieces in place as both ends are moved. You can find a simple example in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42721/935).

It is possible to build more complex rigs, in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/77103/935) a front-end loader rig is setup to move one bone that rotates the scoop as well as the attached parts that would control the movement on a real tractor.